# Babel with browser.js, getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to use Babel in Chrome with the browser.js script.

I created a symlink pointing to the node_modules directory based on my node installation so i can reach browser.js

Right after i add the script as:

i get the following error in my console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ËË†-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë¬Ë®Í°-Í´Í¶Í·Íº-Í½Í¿Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î¡Î£-ÏµÏ·-ÒÒŠ-Ô¯Ô±-Õ–Õ™Õ¡-Ö‡×-×ª×°-×²Ø -ÙŠÙ®Ù¯Ù±-Û“Û•Û¥Û¦Û®Û¯Ûº-Û¼Û¿ÜÜ’-Ü¯Ý-Þ¥Þ±ßŠ-ßªß´ßµßºà €-à •à šà ¤à ¨à¡€-à¡˜à¢ -à¢²à¤„-à¤¹à¤½à¥à¥˜-à¥¡à¥±-à¦€à¦…-à¦Œà¦à¦à¦“-à¦¨à¦ª-à¦°à¦²à¦¶-à¦¹à¦½à§Žà§œà§à§Ÿ-à§¡à§°à§±à¨…-à¨Šà¨à¨à¨“-à¨¨à¨ª-à¨°à¨²à¨³à¨µà¨¶à¨¸à¨¹à©™-à©œà©žà©²-à©´àª…-àªàª-àª‘àª“-àª¨àªª-àª°àª²àª³àªµ-àª¹àª½à«à« à«¡à¬…-à¬Œà¬à¬à¬“-à¬¨à¬ª-à¬°à¬²à¬³à¬µ-à¬¹à¬½à­œà­à­Ÿ-à­¡à­±à®ƒà®…-à®Šà®Ž-à®à®’-à®•à®™à®šà®œà®žà®Ÿà®£à®¤à®¨-à®ªà®®-à®¹à¯à°…-à°Œà°Ž-à°à°’-à°¨à°ª-à°¹à°½à±˜à±™à± à±¡à²…-à²Œà²Ž-à²à²’-à²¨à²ª-à²³à²µ-à²¹à²½à³žà³ à³¡à³±à³²à´…-à´Œà´Ž-à´à´’-à´ºà´½àµŽàµ àµ¡àµº-àµ¿à¶…-à¶–à¶š-à¶±à¶³-à¶»à¶½à·€-à·†à¸-à¸°à¸²à¸³à¹€-à¹†àºàº‚àº„àº‡àºˆàºŠàºàº”-àº—àº™-àºŸàº¡-àº£àº¥àº§àºªàº«àº­-àº°àº²àº³àº½à»€-à»„à»†à»œ-à»Ÿà¼€à½€-à½‡à½‰-à½¬à¾ˆ-à¾Œá€€-á€ªá€¿á-á•áš-áá¡á¥á¦á®-á°áµ-á‚á‚Žá‚ -áƒ…áƒ‡áƒáƒ-áƒºáƒ¼-á‰ˆá‰Š-á‰á‰-á‰–á‰˜á‰š-á‰á‰ -áŠˆáŠŠ-áŠáŠ-áŠ°áŠ²-áŠµáŠ¸-áŠ¾á‹€á‹‚-á‹…á‹ˆ-á‹–á‹˜-áŒáŒ’-áŒ•áŒ˜-ášáŽ€-áŽáŽ -á´á-á™¬á™¯-á™¿áš-áššáš -á›ªá›®-á›¸áœ€-áœŒáœŽ-áœ‘áœ -áœ±á€-á‘á -á¬á®-á°áž€-áž³áŸ—áŸœá  -á¡·á¢€-á¢¨á¢ªá¢°-á£µá¤€-á¤žá¥-á¥­á¥°-á¥´á¦€-á¦«á§-á§‡á¨€-á¨–á¨ -á©”áª§á¬…-á¬³á­…-á­‹á®ƒ-á® á®®á®¯á®º-á¯¥á°€-á°£á±-á±á±š-á±½á³©-á³¬á³®-á³±á³µá³¶á´€-á¶¿á¸€-á¼•á¼˜-á¼á¼ -á½…á½ˆ-á½á½-á½—á½™á½›á½á½Ÿ-á½½á¾€-á¾´á¾¶-á¾¼á¾¾á¿‚-á¿„á¿†-á¿Œá¿-á¿“á¿–-á¿›á¿ -á¿¬á¿²-á¿´á¿¶-á¿¼â±â¿â‚-â‚œâ„‚â„‡â„Š-â„“â„•â„˜-â„â„¤â„¦â„¨â„ª-â„¹â„¼-â„¿â……-â…‰â…Žâ… -â†ˆâ°€-â°®â°°-â±žâ± -â³¤â³«-â³®â³²â³³â´€-â´¥â´§â´­â´°-âµ§âµ¯â¶€-â¶–â¶ -â¶¦â¶¨-â¶®â¶°-â¶¶â¶¸-â¶¾â·€-â·†â·ˆ-â·Žâ·-â·–â·˜-â·žã€…-ã€‡ã€¡-ã€©ã€±-ã€µã€¸-ã€¼ã-ã‚–ã‚›-ã‚Ÿã‚¡-ãƒºãƒ¼-ãƒ¿ã„…-ã„­ã„±-ã†Žã† -ã†ºã‡°-ã‡¿ã€-ä¶µä¸€-é¿Œê€€-ê’Œê“-ê“½ê”€-ê˜Œê˜-ê˜Ÿê˜ªê˜«ê™€-ê™®ê™¿-êšêš -ê›¯êœ—-êœŸêœ¢-êžˆêž‹-êžŽêž-êž­êž°êž±êŸ·-ê ê ƒ-ê …ê ‡-ê Šê Œ-ê ¢ê¡€-ê¡³ê¢‚-ê¢³ê£²-ê£·ê£»ê¤Š-ê¤¥ê¤°-ê¥†ê¥ -ê¥¼ê¦„-ê¦²ê§ê§ -ê§¤ê§¦-ê§¯ê§º-ê§¾ê¨€-ê¨¨ê©€-ê©‚ê©„-ê©‹ê© -ê©¶ê©ºê©¾-êª¯êª±êªµêª¶êª¹-êª½ê«€ê«‚ê«›-ê«ê« -ê«ªê«²-ê«´ê¬-ê¬†ê¬‰-ê¬Žê¬‘-ê¬–ê¬ -ê¬¦ê¬¨-ê¬®ê¬°-ê­šê­œ-ê­Ÿê­¤ê­¥ê¯€-ê¯¢ê°€-íž£íž°-íŸ†íŸ‹-íŸ»ï¤€-ï©­ï©°-ï«™ï¬€-ï¬†ï¬“-ï¬—ï¬ï¬Ÿ-ï¬¨ï¬ª-ï¬¶ï¬¸-ï¬¼ï¬¾ï­€ï­ï­ƒï­„ï­†-ï®±ï¯“-ï´½ïµ-ï¶ï¶’-ï·‡ï·°-ï·»ï¹°-ï¹´ï¹¶-ï»¼ï¼¡-ï¼ºï½-ï½šï½¦-ï¾¾ï¿‚-ï¿‡ï¿Š-ï¿ï¿’-ï¿—ï¿š-ï¿œ]/: Range out of order in character class

**What is this?**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Babel #340](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/340)

You must set the `Content-Type` on the HTML page, or on the JS file header.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
// OR
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
// OR
<script src="scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

or in the headers of the JS file:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have exact same issue and i've tried all 3 options of setting charset from html, and the issue still persists, do you know what else could cause this?

Comment: File is part of a chrome extension that I'm building, in case that makes any difference

Answer (score 3):

Just add the UTF-8 encoding

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```