# Why is simple React project not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I just started learning about React, but I can't seem to understand why React won't render this. I think it has something to do with the React and Babel libraries changing their links because of newer updates, but I'm not sure. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>

  <script type="text/babel">
    ReactDOM.render(
      <h1>Testing</h1>, 
      document.querySelector("#container")
  );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any error on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script sources were slightly off. The following HTML code should work fine.

See [the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) for more info.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.0.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.0.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/babel">

    var Greeting = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
          <p>Hello, Universe</p>
        )
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Greeting/>,
      document.getElementById("container")
    );

  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **add** `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the page's `<head>`.

**Details below**

[image]

You have a console error  `Range out of order in character class` . I came across this [comment](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/340#issuecomment-113982116) on a babel issue ([#340](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/340)) and also a [Stack Overflow question on around same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225606/babel-with-browser-js-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-regular-expression). Just add

Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the page's `<head>` and it will work as expected for you .

[image: OutPut]

Answer (score 0):

As you have just started learning React, I would suggest you use the `create-react-app` basic project by Facebook itself to get started. The installation process is well described [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and all requirements will be downloaded and installed.