# ReactDOM.render is not rendering the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I can't find out why this page isn't showing anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="react-0.14.3.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>

        <script type="text/jsx">
            console.log("Hi Rect!");
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello World</h1>,
                document.getElementById('container')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have placed "react-0.14.3.js" & "react-dom-0.14.3.js" same directory where I have saved my this HTML page.

Comment: React's JSX (your `<h1>Hello World</h1>`) isn't supported by browsers natively; the above is a syntax error. Either use React without JSX, or an in-browser babel transformation. Or even better: get node, npm and create-react-app.

Comment: you need to use React.createElement instead of JSX. It is not supported by browsers.

Comment: also....if you are just starting out, then start out with current version of React (`16.8.6`) instead of ancient version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use JSX in the browser without Babel. To fix that, add the script in `head` and change the type of `script` to `text/babel`. If you want Babel locally, just go to the script [url](https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js) and download the file. I also updated your React versions (which you should definitely do).

React CDN links (you can download the files from there as well): https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html

During development, use the development react scripts. During production, switch over to the production version. The exact links can be found with the other CDN links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">
            console.log("Hi React!");
            ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello World</h1>,
                document.getElementById('container')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Documentation on how to add Babel to browser (source for answer)](https://babeljs.io/en/setup), just click "In the browser" under "Prototyping"

Babel Standalone documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone

NOTE: If you are using local files for Babel, add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to your head. More information on why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225606/babel-with-browser-js-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-regular-expression) and [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/340)

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

But, one thing, if I download all files & place those in the same directory as html file, then - 
script src="react.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="babel.7.5.4.min.js"></script>

is . not working

Comment: But, 

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

are working

Comment: Are the file names correct? If you open up console in your browser, do any errors show up?

Comment: Add this to your head: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`. I updated the answer with information on why.

Comment: <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                
        <script src="react-dom.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="react.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
        <script src="babel.7.5.4.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>

Not working